# enviroment varriables / .env files

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, cloud-foundry

I am working on an application at the moment that have 2 platforms on cloudfoundry where there is a "development" and a "production" space. Obviously I want to use sandbox API keys in my development space and live api keys in my production space.

I have a development and a production branch the `.env` is my `.gitignore` so obviously they don't go up to my repo, but if I run `cf push` the .env file will get pushed up the space. If I switch branch the .env files doesn't get switched because of the .gitignore, so how do I go about making sure my environments use the correct env files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a `.cfignore` file that you could create to ignore the `.env` file from being pushed. The syntax is the same as a `.gitignore` file.

Here is the relevant documentation:
[Limit the Upload Files](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/deploy-app.html#exclude)

Comment: I want the env files to go up, my question is how to do it with putting them into git? If they are not tracked by GIT, and and I switch from development to production branch, the untracked .env file does not change, and therefore the cf push does not change the .env file on the server.

Comment: You would probably be better off using [`cf env`](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html) for managing variables in different environments.

Comment: It's a little hacky, but you could keep both files around, so `.env` is your dev/local file and `.env-prod` is your remote/prod file. Then add a file called `.profile` at the root of your project (from where you run `cf push`). That file is just a script which runs before your app starts up, so you could just put a `mv .env-prod .env` and overwrite the local file with the prod file. That said, using env variables or user provided services is typically what you'd do here.

Answer (score 0):

`cf push` doesn't use `.gitignore`. They uses its own file called `.cfignore`.

If you want to push `.env`, you need to remove `.env` in `.gitignore`.